# Google Maps API V3 & Fusion Tables - Display selected polygon name (as innerHTML) inside sidebar

Tags: javascript, dom, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I menage to find polygons (stored in Fusion Tables) that are inside specific radius and display this polygons on the map.
Now I trying to display name of this polygons (by using innerHTML) inside sidebar, but I have only retrieve "[object Object]" message inside sidebar.

I try to do:

```
document.getElementById('layer').innerHTML = layer;
```

Whole code is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>USA</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

<link href="/apis/fusiontables/docs/samples/style/default.css"
rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var geocoder;
var map;
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var marker;

function initialize() {

  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.857507,-101.000978);

  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
}

//Reverse Geocode
function codeLatLng() {
  var input = document.getElementById('latlng').value;
  var latlngStr = input.split(',', 2);
  var lat = parseFloat(latlngStr[0]);
  var lng = parseFloat(latlngStr[1]);
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
  geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(layers, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      if (layers[1]) {
        map.setZoom(10);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map
        });
        infowindow.setContent(layers[1].formatted_address);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      } else {
        alert('No layers found');
      }
    } else {
      alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
    }
  });
//Reverse Geocode

        var tableid = '15Dce-frPm_D_5gTTG2gKwlWTElkgL7NC1RqDzuY';

        var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
          query: {
            select: 'geometry, name',
            from: tableid,
            where: 'ST_INTERSECTS(geometry, CIRCLE(LATLNG ' + latlng + ', 1))'
          },
        });

        document.getElementById('layer').innerHTML = layer;
        layer.setMap(map);

        // Create a map circle object to visually show the radius.
        var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
          center: latlng,
          radius: 1,
          map: map,
          fillOpacity: 0.2,
          strokeOpacity: 0.5,
          strokeWeight: 1
        });

        // Update the radius when the user makes a selection.
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('radius'),
            'change', function() {
              var meters = parseInt(this.value, 10);
              layer.setOptions({
                query: {
                  select: 'geometry, name',
                  from: tableid,
                  where: 'ST_INTERSECTS(geometry, ' +
                      'CIRCLE(LATLNG ' + latlng + ', ' + meters + '))'
                }
              });

              circle.setRadius(meters);
            });
    }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

  </script>

<style>
      #panel {
        position: absolute;
        top: 20px;
        left: 20px;

        width: 300px;
        z-index: 5;
        background-color: #fff;
        padding: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #333333;
      }
      #latlng {
        width: 150px;
      }
    .style1 {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
</style>

  </head>
  <body>

      <div id="panel">
      <input id="latlng" type="text" value="40.714224,-73.961452">
      <input type="button" value="Reverse Geocode" onclick="codeLatLng()">
    </div>


    <div id="map-canvas" style="position:absolute; left:350px; top:20px; width:900px; height:700px; z-index:1; "></div>
    <div id="panel2" style="position:absolute; padding: 5px; left:20px; top:60px; width:200px; height:200px; border-style:solid; border-width:1px; border-color:#333333; z-index:3; ">
      <p class="style1">Select radius:</p>

        <select name="select" id="radius">
          <option value="1">0 meters</option>
          <option value="5000">5000 meters</option>
          <option value="10000">10,000 meters</option>
          <option value="15000">15,000 meters</option>
          <option value="20000">20,000 meters</option>
          <option value="25000">25,000 meters</option>
        </select>   
      </p>
    </div>
    <div id="layer" style="position:absolute; padding: 5px; left:20px; top:300px; width:200px; height:200px; border-style:solid; border-width:1px; border-color:#333333; z-index:3; ">
      <p class="style1">Radius polygons</p>
      <p>&nbsp; </p>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

I will appreciated any help.

Best,
Darko

Answer (score 0, accepted):

layer is a FusionTablesLayer object.  If you want the data that is in the results of the geocoding operations, that is in the "layers" object, which is a [google.maps.GeocoderResult](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#GeocoderResult)  object.

If you want results from querying the table, that isn't available from the FusionTablesLayer object, you need to query separately for that, either using GViz (the google.visualization library) or the FusionTables API v1.0.  Note that GViz has a limit on the number of rows returned.

[example with sidebar (using GViz)](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_FusionTables_Watershed_Stewards_Map_sidebar2.html)

```
function  createSidebar(query) {
  // https://www.google.com/fusiontables/api/query?sql=SELECT%20ROWID,%20%2A%20FROM%20564705

  //set the query using the parameter
  var queryText = encodeURIComponent(query);
  var query = new google.visualization.Query('http://www.google.com/fusiontables/gvizdata?tq='  + queryText);

  //set the callback function
  query.send(getData);
}

var FTresponse = null;
//define callback function, this is called when the results are returned
function getData(response) {
if (!response) {
  alert('no response');
  return;
}
if (response.isError()) {
  alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
  return;
} 
  FTresponse = response;
  //for more information on the response object, see the documentation
  //http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/reference.html#QueryResponse
  numRows = response.getDataTable().getNumberOfRows();
  numCols = response.getDataTable().getNumberOfColumns();

  //concatenate the results into a string, you can build a table here
  fusiontabledata = "<table><tr>";
  fusiontabledata += "<th>" + response.getDataTable().getColumnLabel(0) + "</th>";
  fusiontabledata += "</tr><tr>";

  for(i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
    fusiontabledata += "<td>"+response.getDataTable().getValue(i, 0) + "</a></td>";
    fusiontabledata += "</tr><tr>";
  }
  fusiontabledata += "</table>"  
  //display the results on the page
  document.getElementById('sidebar').innerHTML = fusiontabledata;
}
```

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_FusionTables_sidebarA.html)

Comment: Thanks again geocodezip on the help, this code works perfectly.